# Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int[] intersect(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        HashSet<Integer> set1= new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (Integer n : nums1)
            set1.add(n);
        HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (Integer n : nums2)
            set2.add(n);
        
        set1.retainAll(set2);
        int[] output = new int[set1.size()];
        int idx=0;
        for(int s :set1)
            output[idx++]=s;
        return output;            
    }
}
```

output

```
Input:
[1,2,2,1]
[2,2]
Output:
[2]
Expected:
[2,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets don't allow duplicates, so they are not suitable if you expect the output to contain duplicates.

You can use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` to count the occurrences of each element of the first array, and then check them against the second array:

```
public int[] intersect(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    for (int n : nums1) {
        if (map1.containsKey(n))
            map1.put(n,map1.get(n)+1);
        else
            map1.put(n,1);
    }
    List<Integer> inter = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n : nums2) {
        Integer count = map1.get(n);
        if (count != null && count > 0) {
            map1.put(n,count-1);
            inter.add(n);
        }
    }
    
    int[] output = new int[inter.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < inter.size(); i++)
        output[i]=inter.get(i);
    return output;
    
}
```